# GoogleUrl cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, google-fusion-tables

On this thread: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/groups/fusionTablesApiGroup?csw=1

It is suggested to use this:

```
String sql = <sql insert statements>
HttpContent content = ByteArrayContent.fromString(null, "sql=" + sql);
GoogleUrl url = new GoogleUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query");
HttpRequest httpRequest = fusiontables.getRequestFactory().buildPostRequest(url, content);
httpRequest.execute();
```

But when I try to use it GoogleUrl cannot be resolved, it is supposed to be in

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUrl
```

but I cannot find it there in any of the libraries. Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: Appears to be [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/google-api-client/src/com/google/api/client/googleapis/GoogleUrl.java?r=25fc14c5bd7c637bd40c5280963bfa9731153b6d)

Comment: Thanks been looking for ages

Comment: It looks like someone set it to be not visible... Just to be annoying so I ended up having to make it.